# Customize Chromium/Google Chrome error pages

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, custom-error-pages

How can I customize the error pages Google Chrome/Chromium displays when there is a networking error (e.g. Error 137 net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED)

I'm talking about these kinds of pages: http://i41.tinypic.com/29qm8v6.png

They don't seem to be stored anywhere on the file system. Can the errors that make them display be trapped using an extension?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, trapping is not possible, and the HTML for the error pages gets built at runtime from compiled resources. See http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/renderer/localized_error.cc?view=markup for the code that builds these error pages.

Answer (score 3):

No :(
Correct link at this moment:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/chrome/renderer/localized_error.cc