# Edit the Google Chrome error page

Tags: google-chrome, intranet, kiosk

I’m developing an intranet kiosk system with screens using Ubuntu and Google Chrome.

When the server is down, naturally the “Ooops! Google Chrome could not...” message is displayed. Is there anyway to edit this page? It doesn’t have to be complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071984/customize-chromium-google-chrome-error-pages

Comment: Unfortunately, not much help to you unless you want to rebuild Chrome. You might consider running web requests through a local proxy. If the proxy can't fetch the page, it can serve a custom "Not Found" page. Just a thought.