# Can I Customize the Chromium error screen

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

A similar (if not identical) question was asked at [Customize Chromium/Google Chrome error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071984/customize-chromium-google-chrome-error-pages) but I wanted to check in since that question is several years old.

We have a bash script that launches chromium when our tablet device starts. However our docker containers that serve the app aren't always fully launched by the time chromium starts, and we see the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` screen.

If we can replace this screen with, say, our logo, then the problem is "solved".

Is this possible?

Comment: Depends on your app, service workers are used for this exact situation.

Comment: The problem is my app isn't running at this point. I need to modify these settings on the local machine.

Comment: could add in the bash script a loop to check the container is up before launching the browser. its alittle unclear what your setup is

Comment: Are you using your own Chromium fork? You can modify the source code to do so